# How to have a mobile version of a MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile

I currently converted my website from classic asp to ASP.NET MVC, I'll be putting it live in a few days. I'm now thinking that I should start supporting mobile device.

I was wondering if this could be a good idea to do things.

- Have the same model
- Have the same controller
- Have two different view and chose the right one using `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice`
- One view for mobile display, one view for everything else.

This way I could keep the same URL.

Is this a good way of doing things?

Comment: see my tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scott Hanselman [blogged about this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx). He illustrated an example of how you could build a custom view engine which depending on the user agent would render a view situated in a different folder. This way you could have the same Model and Controller but different views.

And this functionality will be [built-in out-of-the-box in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features).

Answer (score 0):

For the HTML, CSS, and JS, check out [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) and [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/).  For Bootstrap, check out [this link](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html), scroll down to responsive utility classes and resize your screen.

They are other frameworks out there too that allow you to do similar things as bootstrap as well.